# Maven Apache - Terminal error [cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment]

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm debugging a code not mine, as the first compilation with Maven Apache I get this error. Has anyone managed to fix it?
I assume there is a compactability problem in the pom file.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project mysalepro-common: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed module @0x3cd95b79) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x3cd95b79 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Upgrade the version to the most recent version of the plugin https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change maven version

```
<properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>your version</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>your version</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

if error still persists change the version of Lombok. Link [Lombok version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok) for the latest Lombok version

Comment: Yah, it work! I've update Lombok at the latest version. Thank you